# Configure network manager to expose to VM only

Tags: networking, virtualbox, virtualbox-networking

I am running Xubuntu 20.10, fresh install. I have researched this but I can't find the correct information.

I have 2 separate NICs, one to do DHCP over normal network, the other should only be used by a VM that will run on this machine.

I want to edit netplan in 01-network-manager-all.yaml to accomplish this. As an example under a windows host I do this by going into Network Connections, open properties of the target NIC and I uncheck every box except the one for virtualbox. Then in the VM settings I point to that nic as bridged connection. This Guest VM was already running on a windows host, and I am porting it over. I just need to have the new host set up correctly and it should be seamless to the Guest. I was able to do this once before but I don't know if I did it correctly and it was a few years ago.

Hopefully that is clear enough for what I want to accomplish, now for the information you may need:

```
lspci | grep -i 'ethernet'
01:00.0 Ethernet controller: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries NetXtreme II BCM5709 Gigabit Ethernet (rev 20)
01:00.1 Ethernet controller: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries NetXtreme II BCM5709 Gigabit Ethernet (rev 20)
02:00.0 Ethernet controller: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries NetXtreme II BCM5709 Gigabit Ethernet (rev 20)
02:00.1 Ethernet controller: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries NetXtreme II BCM5709 Gigabit Ethernet (rev 20)
```

From this the DHCP is 02:00.0 and the target NIC for the VM is 01:00.0

```
ip addr
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eno1: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 84:2b:2b:66:0a:b3 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    altname enp1s0f0
3: eno2: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 84:2b:2b:66:0a:b5 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    altname enp1s0f1
4: eno3: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 84:2b:2b:66:0a:b7 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    altname enp2s0f0
    inet 192.168.2.20/24 brd 192.168.2.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute eno3
       valid_lft 83855sec preferred_lft 83855sec
    inet6 fe80::ae20:f9fd:db35:3f95/64 scope link noprefixroute 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
5: eno4: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 84:2b:2b:66:0a:b9 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    altname enp2s0f1
```

From this eno1 (altname enp1s0f0) is the target for this setting and eno3 (altname enp2s0f0) is already working as DHCP as intended.

Finally the current 01-network-manager-all.yaml: (I confirmed this is the correct yaml)

```
# Let NetworkManager manage all devices on this system
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: NetworkManager
```

I hope this is enough information. Let me know if it is not clear.

Comment: Of course I gave up and started trying things. Now I have to wait to call the ISP to see if what I did worked because I definitely exposed the host device and got an IP, so now my device limit is going to be stuck again.

So what I did that might work continuing from the yaml above:
ethernets:
    eno1:
        link-local: []
        dhcp4: no
        addresses: []
        dhcp6: no

This is giving me a good not being used IP in host, but I don't know if it also blocks access to the VM or not.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this using the following settings. Hopefully this will help someone else in the future.

In 01-network-manager-all.yaml I changed it from this:

```
# Let NetworkManager manage all devices on this system
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: NetworkManager
```

To this:

```
#Let NetworkManager manage all devices on this system
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: NetworkManager
  ethernets:
          eno1:
                  link-local: []
                  dhcp4: no
                  addresses: []
                  dhcp6: no
```

Then typed the following command:

```
sudo netplan try
```

I confirmed it was valid and then followed with:

```
sudo netplan apply
```